# IIF in dynamic where condition for filter in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hi i have filter in my sql procedure like this:

```
IF (@LastLoginStartDate IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @sqlFilters = @sqlFilters + 'AND IIF(DPL.[LastLoginDate]=''0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000'',''1901-01-01 00:00:00.0000000'',DPL.[LastLoginDate]) >= @LastLoginStartDateUTC ';
    END
```

But this returns me an error. So how can I put value 1901-01-01 for value like 0001-01-01 and compare with the parameter @LastLoginStartDateUTC?

Error I receive:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 115
Incorrect syntax near 'IIF'.
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (That code is far from ANSI SQL...)

Comment: And show the line *where* the error occurs.  That line looks reasonable, so I double the error is there.

Comment: That code alone throws completely different errors. You should post some code that reproduces your error. I assume you have some crazy dynamic sql going on and you have one too few or too many `'` symbols. Or... your compatibility level might not be SQL 2012. Run this to find out: `SELECT name, compatibility_level FROM sys.databases`. For 2012 (to use `IIF`) your database should be 110 or higher.

Comment: I just want to credit the nice catch of @Nick.McDermaid which is most likely the REAL reason of OP's issue. Never thought about compatibility level which could cause trouble here.

Comment: Why thanks :) It sure is hard to get some acknowledgement round here sometimes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iif is used in Access but is not valid SQL Server.  Instead you should use the CASE syntax like this:

```
AND CASE WHEN DPL.[LastLoginDate]='0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000' 
         THEN '1901-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 ' 
         ELSE DPL.[LastLoginDate] 
    END >= @LastLoginStartDateUTC
```

Comment: `IIF` is valid SQL Server since 2012. It is treated as shorthand for the `CASE WHEN` scenarios and comes with all limitations `CASE WHEN` has. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx

Comment: If this truly solved your problem then you need to take one more step and understand why. Either you indicated the wrong version or your compatibility level is incorrect.